# Send command to running Node.js process

Tags: node.js

I would like my Node.js app to be able to accept commands while running. For example, think of `Nodemon`, where you can type `rs` in the console to reboot the script.

I've considered using process.stdin for this. So, I've created a simple scripts that runs forever and outputs some text in the console every second. I've also added some code adapted from the [process.stdin documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

```
setInterval(function () {
  console.log("Process running");
}, 1000);

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while ((chunk = process.stdin.read()) !== null) {
    console.log(`data: ${chunk}`);
  }
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  console.log("end")
});
```

When I write `HelloWorld` in the console, this is what I get:
[image: Picture]

It's clearly not doing what I want. I'm really not sure if stdin is the correct api to handle commands, and if it is what is wrong in my code?

Any opinion on that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The example from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) of Node.js did not work, at least not with Node.js v11.13.0. The issue seems to be located in the while loop.

I modified the example to this and now it works.

```
import os from "os";

setInterval(function () {
  console.log("Process running");
}, 3000);

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");


process.stdin.on("readable", function () {
  const chunk = process.stdin.read() as string;
  chunk
    .split(os.EOL)
    .forEach(str => {
      if (str === null || !str.length) {
        return;
      }

      console.log("data: " + str);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd to get commands and perform your action in the callback

Answer (score -1):

Install pm2 module and run the following command

`pm2 start <yourjs file> --watch`

This will restart your server each time change is detected.

Refer docs for additional info 
https://pm2.io/