# How do you change the directory of the terminal in a Node JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I do `node someCommand.js`. I want this command to change the directory of the terminal.

When I tried `process.chdir(newDir)`, that just changes the directory in the context of the script - once the command exits, the terminal is still in the old directory.

Comment: What do you want to do? `process.chdir(newDir)` did the work for you no?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577799/send-command-to-running-node-js-process

Comment: Ironically, the `node` executable has options to specify the diagnostic directory, the heap profiler directory, the report directory but not the current directory, so probably they expect you to just run `cd /somedir` before running node.

Comment: [You can't, and you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2375003/1048572).

Comment: @GOTO0 the current working directory is not an environment variable. Doing `cd` in a shell is the way to go. See also [Specifying working directory when starting process on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/396394/175275) and [How does Unix keep track of the working directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413204/190272)

Comment: @Bergi thank you. That's a shame that it cannot be done :(

Comment: I'm not even sure *why* you would want to do that though